# show that $\int_1^\infty |\sin t/t| {\rm d}t= \infty,$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing

$$\int_1^\infty \left|\frac{\sin \pi t}{t}\right| {\rm d}t= \infty,$$

I am trying to figure how to show this. My first attempt (and the tip that was given to us) was calculating the areas of the triangles with vertices $(n,0)$, $(n+1,0)$ and $\left(n+\frac12, \frac{1}{n+\frac12}\right)$ 
this led me to think that if I was able to prove that the following inequality holds for all n in the naturals it would be easy to prove the whole problem . I tried to do an induction proof but it did not work.
$$\int_n^{n+1} \left|\frac{\sin\pi t}{t}\right| {\rm d}t > \frac{1}{2n+1}$$
If you have any ideas of how to approach this problem I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler inequality which does not use your hint:
$$\int_n^{n+1}\left|\frac{\sin \pi t}{t}\right|dt
  \ge\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\left|\sin \pi t\right|}{n+1}dt
  =\frac2\pi\frac1{n+1}\ .$$
The sum of the RHS for $n\ge1$ is divergent.